# Java could not resolve to a variable

Tags: java, scope

```
if(text.contains(authcode) && text.contains("balance")){
    String balUser = text.split("]")[0];
    event.getSession().send(new ClientChatPacket("/money"));
}
if(text.contains("Balance: $")){
    text = text.split(": ")[1];
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    event.getSession().send(new ClientChatPacket("/m " + balUser + text));
}
```

Unfortunately balUser (In the second IF statement) is highlighted in eclipse  as 'Cannot be resolved to a variable'. I was just wondering if I have done some incorrect syntax somewhere.

Comment: You're only declaring `balUser` in the first `if` statement - it's not in scope for the second.

Comment: Please format your code when posting questions - think of it from the perspective of someone who reads your question and might want to answer it. Is your post in the format they'd want to see? If not, fix it. (And in this case, it definitely isn't...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The `balUser` is defined in the scope of the `if`. Just define it outside the `if` statement:

```
String balUser = null;
if(text.contains(authcode) && text.contains("balance")) {
    balUser = ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. Be back in nine minutes to select your answer!

Comment: The only problem is, this chunk of text is inside another if statement that is run many times, so each time it resets my variable back to null (which is bad). Is there a way to set a variable outside both if statements and access it inside?

Comment: Yes. In the same manner just define the `String balUser = null;` outside the top-level if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your `balUser` `String` within the first `if` statement, hence it is scoped locally.

Declare it outside the first `if` statement and check for `null`s in the second to make this go away.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `String balUser` is declared inside a pair of curly brackets, so it's scope is limited to that block of code.

if you want it to be known elsewhere, you need to declare it where it can be seen by both blocks.

In your case:

```
String balUser = null; // variable declared here
if(text.contains(authcode) && text.contains("balance")){
    balUser = text.split("]")[0]; // remove declaration, just assignation
    event.getSession().send(new ClientChatPacket("/money"));
}
    if(text.contains("Balance: $")){
        text = text.split(": ")[1];
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    event.getSession().send(new ClientChatPacket("/m " + balUser + text));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared the variable `balUser` inside the first if statement, so its scope is that first if statement. You should declare it outside of the if statement if you want to use it elsewhere.

```
String balUser = null;
if(text.contains(authcode) && text.contains("balance")){
    balUser = text.split("]")[0];
    event.getSession().send(new ClientChatPacket("/money"));
}
if(text.contains("Balance: $")){
    text = text.split(": ")[1];
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    event.getSession().send(new ClientChatPacket("/m " + balUser + text));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Examine your code structure:

```
if() {
    String balUser = ...;
} else {
    event.getSession().send( ...   balUser);
}
```

I hope that now it is obvious that the variable is declared in fist block and is referenced in second block where it does not exist. Generally scope of all identifiers in java and all c-like languages is limited by a pair of surrounding `{` and `}`. The inner scope however can see identifiers from the outer scope, so this code is correct:

```
int i = 5;
{
   int j = i;
}
```